# resolving onAction='#initialize', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script

Tags: java, javafx

This is my first program in javafx. I have just created a AnchorPane with the help of scene Builder. what I want from this is when we click any where in the AncherPane it should show the coordinate point of that pixel.
This is the controller class

```
package application;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
public class AxisController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchr;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         assert anchr != null : "fx:id=\"anchr\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'AxisFxml.fxml'.";
         anchr.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                System.out.println(event.getX());
                System.out.println(event.getY());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="anchr" onMouseClicked="#initialize" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.AxisController">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</AnchorPane>
```

Error Message

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onAction='#initialize', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script.
/home/xyz/workspace/AxisExample/bin/application/AxisFxml.fxml:9

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:610)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.AxisMain.start(AxisMain.java:16)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of misunderstandings here.

The methods whose names you set as values to the "event handler attributes", such as `onMouseClicked`, are the methods that will be invoked when those events happen. They should just contain the code that you want to be executed when, in this case, the mouse is clicked. You should not register event handlers in these methods. (This would mean: "when the anchor pane is clicked, register an event handler for the anchor pane being clicked", which is clearly not what you intend.)

As a consequence of this, methods that are registered in the FXML as event handler methods should take a single parameter of the correct event type. (It is also allowable to take no parameters, if you don't need the event object - a common scenario.)

The error you are getting is because the method you have declared to be the event handler (`initialize()`, which has a completely different role), has the wrong signature: it take the wrong number (and type) of parameters.

Secondly, the `initialize()` method, which may either be declared with no parameters, or be declared with parameters of type `URL` and `ResourceBundle`, is invoked during the process of loading the FXML. This happens after all the `@FXML`-annotated fields have been injected, but before the root of the UI is returned from the call to `FXMLLoader.load()`. Thus it's safe to access `@FXML`-annotated fields here: they will have been properly initialized.

So there are two distinct ways of registering event handlers.

**Either**:

Define a method in the controller, and reference it in the FXML file:

```xml
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchr" onMouseClicked="#handleClick" ... fx:controller="application.AxisController">
    <!-- TODO Add Nodes -->
</AnchorPane>
```

and then

```
public class AxisController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchr;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
         assert anchr != null : "fx:id=\"anchr\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'AxisFxml.fxml'.";

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleClick(MouseEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getX());
        System.out.println(event.getY());
    }
}
```

**Or:**

Remove the `onMouseClicked` attribute from the FXML file, and register the event handler in the `initialize()` method. (So the controller is exactly as you have it.)

Comment: @gawaruCoder Yes sorry, had that parameter missing. Now fixed.

Comment: D yaa I have set the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the problem lies in your anchorPane on your FXML, have you assigned a function to the anchorPane for a click event on your FXML? if you have you can set the function for that event by doing the same as if you where initializing the variable for example:

```
@FXML
private void restartExited() {
    exitedTransition(0, "circle", null, buttonCirc);
}
```

you can tell your anchorPane in the FXML to do this function when it is clicked or mouseOver for example, you do not need to set it in the controller as well as the FXML.

Or in your case:

```
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    anchr.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event.getX());
            System.out.println(event.getY());
        }
    });
}
```

Or you could remove the reference to onClick on the AnchorPane in your FXML and use your current code.

**EDIT**

Can I ask where you are defining the stage and the FXML to load to the stage, is this your stage initializer for your application or the controller for the FXML?